# jQuery mobile: hrefs in new page to internal pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

All,

Quick question: I've got this app I'm building in jQM. I've got my pages configured by sections (I.e., all pages/divs for a certain feature under one HTML file, and so on... a la page1.html, page1.html#sectionB, ...)

When I click from, say, index.html to section1.html, it all works great, AJAX and all.

However, once I'm in section1.html, I can't link to #sectionB. Ajax simply won't fire. I can get a console log output, so the link is working. I've tried it with a $.mobile.changePage('#sectionB') click event, but no luck.

If I open the page directly, navigation to all the internal pages works great, though.

I know jQM loads pages into the DOM on demand, but is it looking at the wrong html file f the pages or something, and that's why it can't find them?

Thank you in advance!

N

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: Definitely agree, Cody. I was just typing on my phone, so I didn't have access to the source at that moment! :)

Answer (score 0):

In index.html put data-ajax="false" on link to page1.html. You might be approaching your app creation all wrong though - I know I did when I first got started with JQM. Try placing all your "sections" in index.html and have a static footer with buttons. With onclick load the page/divs accordingly.

```
<a data-ajax="false" href="page1.html">Page One</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I ended up doing that — actually, I used rel="external" instead, but it's six of one, half a dozen of the other...

At some point, I might bundle everything into one single index.html file, as the app gets closer to production. I worry that it might become a bit too big to manage, though — know what I mean? Right now, I'm building a lot of the DOM in the section pages programmatically, in order to keep it smaller and easier to read, but it still adds up to a large file. Right now, for the sake of the team developing different sections, we're keeping it in separate files. Thanks!